# Power BI refresh data source Azure Data lake

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have a Data Lake source that is a json file that is culled from our SQL Database. The connection worked fine to load the data initially but I can't get the schedule button in Power BI online to work. When I do so, it says that the credentials are incorrect. When I reenter them with oauth2 it says that the credentails are invalid even though I just logged into it from my microsoft account.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how I can get it to refresh daily after our pull happens?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution by any chance?

Comment: Nothing yet. Still waiting for MS.

Answer (score 0):

What caused the issue for us at the end is that powerbi was pointing to the folder, where there was a single resource(file), to which the user did not have access to. This resulted into an overal "credentials are incorrect". This file was uploaded by the service principal account, and somehow the regular user lost the permissions. Perhaps just try to create a new empty folder in the Data Lake Store and point your PowerBI to it. Or, better, create a new fresh user, give him access, and use in PowerBI credentials (this worked for us)